# How to configure Visual Studio Code to work with Node.js

Tags: node.js, intellisense, visual-studio-code

I have Visual Studio Code and I use it to write my Node.js applications. In tutorials I see that Visual Studio Code has IntelliSense and other debugging tools related to Node.js, but I don't find it when I write my apps so is there any extension, or how can I configure it to work with Node.js?

This is the first time for me to ask a question related to configuration not to code, so please be patient.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a plugin for Visual Studio.

You can find more information about this here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools#readme

Comment: Is this for visual studio and visual studio code ??

Comment: Seems to be for Visual Studio, but it's open source and free. Might be worthwhile to give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

My project's working config `${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/test-script.js",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "preLaunchTask": null,
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy"
            ],
            "env": {
                "PROFILE": "development"
            },
            "externalConsole": false,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outDir": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5858,
            "address": "localhost",
            "restart": false,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outDir": null,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "remoteRoot": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to Process",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command.PickProcess}",
            "port": 5858,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outDir": null
        }
    ]
}
```

NodeJS is in the `%Path%`:

```
>node -v
v6.7.0
```